# Assign valuefield and textfield to listbox

Tags: c#

i develop a webpage in that i need to add value field and text field to listbox item 
i tried the following code ,  but it's not working , Please help me to solve the issue . 
Thanks in advance

```
    string[] category = new string[100];
            char[] delimeter = { '~' };
            category = Convert.ToString(dtable.Rows[0].ItemArray[5]).Split(delimeter);

            for (int h = 0; h < category.Length; h++)
            {
                ListItem lstitem = lstCategory.Items.FindByText(category[h]);
                if (lstitem != null)
                {
                    lstSelCategory.DataTextField = category[h];
                    lstSelCategory.DataValueField = lstitem.Value;
                }
            }
            lstSelCategory.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: You'll need to define "not working".

Comment: On a side note, why are you declaring category as a string[100] when you're just reassigning the variable to something that can be string[anything]?

Comment: just for testing purpose i give 100 , Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataValueField` and `DataTextField` are for assigning which properties are displayed and used as values for the assigned `DataSource`, NOT for adding items to the List.

**EDIT:**
It looks to me as though you're looping through some categories from a `DataTable`, finding a matching item in another `ListBox` and then trying to add that item to another `ListBox`... You should be using the `Add` method of the ListBox (if that's what the Control is).

```
lstSelCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem(category[h], lisitem.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox.DataTextField` and `ListBox.DataValueField` are used in conjuction with `ListBox.DataSource`.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx) for further information.